# Recursively remove element from start and end of list at same time

Tags: c#

I want to remove the element from start as well as end of the list at the same time if the first and last element satisfy the condition.

I have a class name Day as below

```
public class Day
{
    public String Name{get; set;}
    public bool IsActive{get; set;}
}
```

I have a list `IList<Day> Days` which contains all the days. Now I want to remove the element from start as well as from end if the start or end element in the list i.e Day fullfills this condition: `Day.IsActive == true`.

I want to keep removing element from the list both from start and end(to make it more efficient) at the same time untill the point where list does not have element at start and end where `Day.IsActive == true`

So cases could be

1. active-inactive-inactive-active-active
2. active-active
3. active-inactive
4. inactive-inactive

This is what I came up with, which solves the problem, but is there better way that I can do

```
public IList<Day> RemoveDays(IList<Day> days) 
        {
            while (days.Count > 0 && (days.First().IsActive || days.Last().IsActive))
            {
                if(days.First().IsActive)
                    days.RemoveAt(0);
                if (days.Count > 0 && days.Last().IsActive)
                    days.RemoveAt(days.Count - 1);
                return RemoveDays(days);
            }

            return days;
        }
```

Comment: So in other words you want to remove all elements that are IsActive == true?

Comment: @KosalaW not necessarily, following OP's logic, it could be `active - inactive - active - inactive - active`.  which would result in `inactive - active - inactive`

Comment: @Jonesopolis:Ok Thanks. Got it. Let me think.

Comment: @King remove from the front, then remove from the back.  what problem are you having? show some code.

Comment: What makes it "recursive" or do you just mean "repeatedly"?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Your first sentence says that you want to prevent a list that has active elements at *both* ends. Your last sentence says that you want to prevent having an active element at *either* end. Which is it?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is. Whenever there I see IsActive true at start or end, I just want to remove it. Its more like Trim function to remove trailing and leading whitespaces if any. So cases could be active-inactive-inactive-active-active or active-active or active-inactive or inactive-inactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with, hope it will help others.

```
public IList<Day> RemoveDays(IList<Day> days)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (days.Count <= 0 || !(days.First().IsActive || days.Last().IsActive)) return days;
        if (days.First().IsActive)
            days.RemoveAt(0);
        if (days.Count > 0 && days.Last().IsActive)
            days.RemoveAt(days.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple LINQ solution: `var newlist = days.SkipWhile(d => d.IsActive).Reverse().SkipWhile(d => d.IsActive).Reverse().ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
            while (list.Count > 2)
            {
                if (list[0].IsActive || list[list.Count - 1].IsActive)
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
                    list.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
```

---

Update 1:

> Now I want to remove the element from start as well as from end if the
>   start or end element in the list i.e Day fullfiles this condition:
>   Day.IsActive == true.

According to your statement, I thought you are asking for the element to be removed if start or end had IsActive=true

If not, use the following

```
            while (list.Count > 2)
            {
                if (list[0].IsActive && list[list.Count - 1].IsActive)
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(list.Count - 1);
                    list.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: This code will remove element from both start and end if either start or end or both has IsActive=true. But what if start or end is not IsActive=true. It will still remove it. Purpose of this function is to remove element from start and end with IsActive=true.

Comment: @King Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that does that. I assumed the recursive part of the task is required so it's done recursively instead of iterative approach:

```
class Program
{
    public static IList<Day> ClearList(IList<Day> days)
    {
        return days.First().IsActive && days.Last().IsActive ?
            ClearList((days.Skip(1).Take(days.Count - 2)).ToList()) :
            days;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Day> days = new List<Day>
        {
            new Day {IsActive = true, Name="M" },
            new Day {IsActive = true, Name="T" },
            new Day {IsActive = false, Name="W" },
            new Day {IsActive = false, Name="Th" },
            new Day {IsActive = true, Name="F" },
            new Day {IsActive = true, Name="St" },
            new Day {IsActive = true, Name="Su" },
        };

        var cleared = ClearList(days);
    }
}
```

Inside the `ClearList` method first there is a check if both ends are active. If so skip first take as all others apart from the last one and pass it to the `ClearList` method again. Otherwise, return the collection.

Comment: But what happen according to this code, if there isis only IsActive in the start or in the end or both or neither.

Comment: Not exactly. Note that you have an `&&` (and) condition. So the code will trigger if `days.First().IsActive` and `days.Last().IsActive` otherwise it will return the collection because at least on of the conditions is not true. Remember that with booleans `day.IsActive` is equivalent to `day.IsActive == true`.

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed you had &&, sorry about that but what will happen of there is only active at start or end. It won't remove it. I just added few cases in my question for more clearity

Comment: That's where recursive methods kicks in. You don't have to remove anything. You just have to pass in a shorter list to the `ClearList` method and the method performs the check again but now on a new list that doesn't have the first and last item (because we checked in previous run of the `ClearList` method that both days are active). Shortening the list is a task of this bit `(days.Skip(1).Take(days.Count - 2)).ToList()`. It creates a new List but skips first item and doesn't take the last item. Run the code I created and you will see you end up with a list that has 3 items.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll run some test cases. But curious how iterative approach will look like?

Comment: Like you said I end up with list containing 3 items but according to my question, I should end up with only two items false-false as function should eliminate all the true that are in end and at start

Comment: Actually in your description you give two (mutually exclusive) descriptions: 1) "remove the element from start as well as from end if the **start or end** element in the list i.e Day fullfills this condition: Day.IsActive == true". And then 2) "I want to keep removing element from the list both from start and end(to make it more efficient) at the same time untill the point where list does not have element at **start and end** where Day.IsActive == true"

Answer (score 0):

How about a Linq flavored recursive approach ?

```
public static List<Day> Check(List<Day> days) {
    if (days.Count < 2)
        return days;
    else if (days.First().IsActive || days.Last().IsActive) {
        var daysInBetween = days.Take(days.Count - 1).Skip(1);
        return Check(daysInBetween);
    }
    else
        return days;
}
```

Comment: This code will remove element from both start and end if either start or end or both has IsActive=true. But what if start or end is not IsActive=true. It will still remove it. Purpose of this function is to remove element from start and end with IsActive=true. The only reason I want to check start and end at the same time is to make it more efficient.

Comment: Frankly, I find your comment paradoxical to what you explained in question. Beside, efficiency achieved with this kind of tweaks is usually quite negligible.

Comment: I just editied question with an implementation of mine that solves the issue, but is there any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following implements a trim method that removes active items from start and end. There's no particular benefit to doing this recursively, nor is there much benefit to doing paired removal.

Because removing from the front is an O(n) operation (i.e. it ends up copying every element in the list), probably the fastest way to do this is to remove active elements from the end, then remove from the front:

```
while (theList.Count > 0 && theList[theList.Count-1].IsActive)
{
    theList.RemoveAt(theList.Count-1);
}
```

Now determine how many to remove from the front.

```
int ix = 0;
while (theList[ix].IsActive)
{
    ++ix;
}

// copy remaining items to the front
int dest = 0;
if (ix > 0)
{
    for (int i = ix; i < theList.Count-1; ++i)
    {
        theList[dest] = theList[i];
        ++dest;
    }
    // and remove the last ix items from the end
    while (ix > 0)
    {
        theList.RemoveAt(theList.Count-1);
        --ix;
    }
}
```

That does the operation in-place. If you're okay with creating a new list, then it's much easier:

```
int lastItem = theList.Count-1;
while (theList.Count > 0 && theList[lastItem].IsActive)
{
    lastItem = lastItem - 1;
}

int firstItem = 0;
while (theList[firstItem].IsActive)
{
    ++firstItem;
}

// copy items to create a new list
theList = theList.Skip(firstItem)
    .Take(lastItem - firstItem)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I just updated my question with few cases. This function will act like a Trim function used on string for removing whitespace from the start and end if any. The reason I want to look at both start and end at same time is to make it more efficient

Comment: @King: See my updated answer. There is no significant performance gain to be had by looking at start and end at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I'll run some test case against.

Comment: I just editied question with an implementation of mine that solves the issue, but is there any better way to do it.

Comment: @King: If you simply must do it recursively, your algorithm will work. Although you don't need a `while` there. Just replace the `while` with an `if`, and it'll work just as well.

Comment: Thanks @Jim I'll replace while with if. Is there any other changes you think will help to make it more efficient

Comment: @King: The optimization opportunity is to use the counting method similar to what I wrote in my answer. You can implement that recursively. The key is that you want to avoid calling `RemoveAt(0)` multiple times.

Comment: I'm having difficulty in converting my code into LINQ, is it possible that you can help me with it. See the solution in my answer I posted